# Do NPCs use the same perk trees as player characters?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

My Level 18 Argonian assassin was recently decapitated by a Bandit Chief's battleaxe power attack.

For this feat to be performed by a player would require the "Devastating Blow" Two-Handed Perk.

Did this Bandit Chief have the perk, or a special NPC-only equivalent decapitation ability?  If it was the perk, should I assume he had all the prerequisite perks as well?

Have others observed instances of NPCs (including companions) using perk-exclusive abilities?

Comment: interesting question, I wonder if its possible to add/remove perks to NPCs via the console....

Answer (score 6):

I saw Karliah perform a Silent Roll which is Sneak 100. You may want to look at http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Classes for more information.

Comment: silent roll is actually sneak 50, but good to know nevertheless

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely. Mages dualcast, tanks are stagger resistant (even against my spells, grr) archers move faster with the bow drawn. I've seen all of these perks used by higher level enemy npcs. It's nuts.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need perks to dual cast or to resist stagger attacks.  NPCs don't have perks.  The "silent roll" is a glitch because a follower will mimic your movements.  If you walk, they walk, if you run, they run, if you sneak, they sneak, and if you forward roll they forward roll.

Answer (score -1):

they probabbly do, as they also 'level up', like in most illusion spells, says that there is a  limit that will affect the creature up to level something.
its best to avoid stronger enemies and let you follower do the work :D

i had sven attacking a dragon and a dog to assist him, i thought they were both dead as sven was incinerated and the dog eaten by the dragon, i killed the dragon and turned my back and saw sven and the dog unharmed and was just acting normal.

Comment: can you explain which perk is described by the anecdote of Sven and the dog? it'll help me copy-edit your answer - thanks!